# Finding trouble in generating the list of all Students who belongs to the major named as “CS” but not to major named as “EE”

Tags: sql, join, select, group-by

```
S_id int Primary Key,
S_name varchar(100),
Gpa float ,
Size_hs int 
)

Create  table Apply (
s_id int ,
C_name varchar(100),
Major varchar(10),
Decision varchar(2)
)


insert into Students values (123,'Amy',3.9,1000)
insert into Students values (234,'Bob',3.6,1500)
insert into Students values (345,'Craig',3.5,500)
insert into Students values (456,'Doug',3.9,1000)
insert into Students values (567,'Edward',2.9,2000)
insert into Students values (678,'Fay',3.8,200)
insert into Students values (789,'Gray',3.4,800)
insert into Students values (987,'Helen',3.7,800)
insert into Students values (876,'Irene',3.9,400)
insert into Students values (765,'Jay',2.9,1500)
insert into Students values (654,'Amy',3.9,1000)
insert into Students values (543,'Craig',3.4,2000)


insert into Apply values (123,'NJIT','CS','Y')
insert into Apply values (123,'NJIT','EE','N')
insert into Apply values (123,'Stoony Brook','CS','Y')
insert into Apply values (123,'Cornell','EE','Y')
insert into Apply values (234,'Stoony Brook','Bio','N')
insert into Apply values (345,'WPI','Bio-Eng','Y')
insert into Apply values (345,'Cornell','Bio-Eng','N')
insert into Apply values (345,'Cornell','CS','Y')
insert into Apply values (345,'Cornell','EE','N')
insert into Apply values (678,'NJIT','Hist','Y')
insert into Apply values (987,'NJIT','CS','Y')
insert into Apply values (987,'Stoony Brook','CS','Y')
insert into Apply values (876,'NJIT','Bio','N')
insert into Apply values (876,'WPI','Marine-Bio','Y')
insert into Apply values (876,'WPI','Hist','N')
insert into Apply values (765,'NJIT','Hist','Y')
insert into Apply values (765,'Cornell','Hist','N')
insert into Apply values (765,'Cornell','Psych','Y')
insert into Apply values (543,'WPI','CS','N')
```

Create table Students(
S_id int Primary Key,
S_name varchar(100),
Gpa float ,
Size_hs int 
)

Create  table Apply (
s_id int ,
C_name varchar(100),
Major varchar(10),
Decision varchar(2)
)

insert into Students values (123,'Amy',3.9,1000)
insert into Students values (234,'Bob',3.6,1500)
insert into Students values (345,'Craig',3.5,500)
insert into Students values (456,'Doug',3.9,1000)
insert into Students values (567,'Edward',2.9,2000)
insert into Students values (678,'Fay',3.8,200)
insert into Students values (789,'Gray',3.4,800)
insert into Students values (987,'Helen',3.7,800)
insert into Students values (876,'Irene',3.9,400)
insert into Students values (765,'Jay',2.9,1500)
insert into Students values (654,'Amy',3.9,1000)
insert into Students values (543,'Craig',3.4,2000)

insert into Apply values (123,'NJIT','CS','Y')
insert into Apply values (123,'NJIT','EE','N')
insert into Apply values (123,'Stoony Brook','CS','Y')
insert into Apply values (123,'Cornell','EE','Y')
insert into Apply values (234,'Stoony Brook','Bio','N')
insert into Apply values (345,'WPI','Bio-Eng','Y')
insert into Apply values (345,'Cornell','Bio-Eng','N')
insert into Apply values (345,'Cornell','CS','Y')
insert into Apply values (345,'Cornell','EE','N')
insert into Apply values (678,'NJIT','Hist','Y')
insert into Apply values (987,'NJIT','CS','Y')
insert into Apply values (987,'Stoony Brook','CS','Y')
insert into Apply values (876,'NJIT','Bio','N')
insert into Apply values (876,'WPI','Marine-Bio','Y')
insert into Apply values (876,'WPI','Hist','N')
insert into Apply values (765,'NJIT','Hist','Y')
insert into Apply values (765,'Cornell','Hist','N')
insert into Apply values (765,'Cornell','Psych','Y')
insert into Apply values (543,'WPI','CS','N')

Basically I have to find the list of students id who belongs to major named as 'Cs' but not to the major  'EE'. I tried it by myself but it is not working properly.
Here is the code below:

````
select * from students
where s_id in (
  select s_id 
  from apply
  where major='CS' and Major!='EE'
  group by s_id
)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `exists` and `not exists`:

```
select s.* 
from students s
where 
    exists (select 1 from applies a where a.s_id = s._id  and a.major = 'CS')
    and not exists (select 1 from applies a where a.s_id = s._id  and a.major = 'EE')
```

With an index on `applies(s_id, major)`, this should be an efficient option.

Another approach is to join, aggregate, and filter with a `having` clause. This requires listing the columns that you want to show in both the `select` and `group by` clauses:

```
select s.s_id, s.s_name
from students s
inner join applies a on a.s_id = s.s_id
where a.major in ('CS', 'EE')
group by s.s_id, s.s_name
having 
    max(case when a.major = 'CS' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
    and max(case when a.major = 'EE' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Note: `apply` is a reserved word in a number a databases (SQL Serer, Oracle, ...), hence not a good choice for a table name. I renamed it to `applies` in the queries.